# Почему, если в проекте есть main функция, не находятся тесты gtest?

Tags: c++, cmake

Если я добавляю в исходники файл **entry_point.cpp**

```
int main(){
  return 0;
}
```

то при запуске тестов, они не находятся

```
cmake ..
cd .. 
cmake --build build
cd build/
ctest
```

Получаю сообщение, что тесты не найдены.

```
No tests were found!!!
```

Но, если убрать файл **entry_point.cpp** из сборки, то все будет работать.

Файл **cmake**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(my_project)

# GoogleTest requires at least C++11
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/refs/heads/main.zip
)

# For Windows: Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker settings
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

enable_testing()

add_executable(
    hello_test 
    #src/MI.entry_point.cpp
    src/Base/MI.fast_mod_unittest.cpp
    src/Base/MI.fast_mod.h
)
target_link_libraries(hello_test gtest_main)
target_link_libraries(hello_test gmock_main)

include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(hello_test)
```

Наверное, нужно создавать два проекта, один с тестами, другой с функцией main?

Comment: В проекте с тестами всегда должна быть функция `main`, так как это точка входа в приложение. Тесты не находятся, так в приведенном примере в `main` они не вызываются. Надо либо запускать тесты вручную, либо использовать библиотечную точку входа. Собственно библиотечная точка входа тут уже линкуется `gtest_main`, непонятно, зачем было еще свою писать.

Comment: У меня же должна быть функция main, чтобы я программу мог запустить. Я не понимаю.

Comment: Тестовая программа - это .exe в котором выполняются тесты. Если вы еще свое приложение пишите - то это еще один .exe. Если они используют общий код - то это должна быть еще библиотека

Comment: `У меня же должна быть функция main` - неверно. Првильно: "программа должна содержать функцию main." Т.е. необязательно чтобы ее определили именно вы. В данном случае она содержится в gtest_main. Вот ее исходный текст: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/googletest/src/gtest_main.cc см. также: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457856/whats-the-difference-between-gtest-lib-and-gtest-main-lib